# disable jQuery qTip mouse events

Tags: jquery, qtip

How can I keep qTip from automatically showing and hiding the tooltips on mouseenter mouseleave events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, you can register for the "beforeShow" event and returning false will stop the tooltip from showing.

So something along the lines of this

```
$("your jquery selector").qtip({ api: { beforeShow: function(event) { return false; } } });
```

Comment: but I want it to show, but not when the mouseenter and mouseleave events fire. I only want it to show when I call .qtip('show')

Comment: What about some sort of logic whereby you set a variable (eg. canShowTooltip) to true before calling the .qtip('show'), and then in the before show event you check to see if the variable is true, and if it's not, then you don't show, else you show and reset the variable by setting it to false?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the events that will cause the tooltip to hide in the `hide` option:

```
$('#tooltip').qtip({     
   hide: {
      when: 'mouseenter mouseleave'
   }
});
```

or you can try setting the `when` attribute in the `show` option to false:

```
$('#tooltip').qtip({     
   show: {
          ready: false, /* Don't show the tooltip once its ready */
          when: false /*  Prevents the tooltip from showing for any event */  
   }
});
```

Comment: Would when:false cause it to not show even when calling .qtip('show') manually?

Comment: @LordZardeck - `when:false` will prevent the tooltip from showing when any event occurs. It will not prevent the tooltip from showing when you explicitly call the api to show the tooltip like `.qtip('show')`

Comment: well, I had tried that and it wouldn't work. I even tried ready: true and that didn't work.

Comment: I tried this and worked. You have to add  hide: { when:false }

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have and works. 
It disables mouse events and tool tips is trigger by `qtip("show")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link1').qtip({
    content: 'This is a tool tip',
    show: {
      event: false
    },
    hide: {
      event:false
    }
  })

  $('#link1').qtip("show");
});
```

Comment: That one is nice, to make it work in current version of qTip just replace key-word "when" with "event"